# Validity check: Prove irrationalilty of $\sqrt{2}$ using $2$-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am currently trying to understand the basics of $p$-adic integers using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNumber.html.

I quote "the equation $x^2=2$ can easily be shown to have no solutions in the field of $2$-adic numbers (we simply take the valuation of both sides)". I tried to prove it to see whether I handle the definitions properly. My proof is as follows:

Assume there exists a rational number $x = \frac{r}{s}\cdot 2^a$ for which $x^2 = 2$, where $r,s$ are odd and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $x^2 = \frac{r^2}{s^2}\cdot2^{2a}$, hence $|x^2|_2 = \frac{1}{2^{2a}}$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, $|2|_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. It follows that $1 = 2a$ which cannot be true because both sides have opposing parity.

Am I doing this correct?

Comment: Not really. Assume there exists $x \in \mathbb{Q}_2^*, x^2 =2$ . Thus $x = 2^a b$ with $|b|_2 = 1$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Looking at $|.|_2$ then $a = 0$  and $b^2 = 2$, which is impossible since $|b|_2^2 = 1 \ne |2|_2=1/2$

Comment: Maybe it’s my additive orientation, but I think it’s **so** much easier to argue with the additive valuation $v=v_2:\Bbb Q_2^\times\to\Bbb Z$, satisfying the rule $v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$, and $v_2(2)=1$. Any square root of $2$, call it $x$, would have to satisfy $v(x)=1/2\notin\Bbb Z$. Thus impossible. And by the way, that Wolfram article is dreadful. There gotta be better descriptions of the $p$-adic world.